# Tkintr/Pandas: Selecting a CSV and editing with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to grab a filepath using a drop down menu with Tkintr, then edit that CSV using Pandas.

Here's the code:

---

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory, askopenfilename
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
import pandas as pd


def testPandas(filePath):
    data = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    data.drop(data.index[[1,2]])
    data.to_csv(filePath, index = False)

def wrapQuotes(fileString):
    return "'{}'".format(fileString)


Tk().withdraw() #get rid of of the tkinter window
tkmb.showinfo(title=' ', message='Select File')
filePath = askopenfilename() #dialogue box for original file

wrapQuotes(filePath)
testPandas(filePath)


print(filePath)
```

---

Here's the CSV:

[image]

---

The process I'm going with is:

(1) Using tkintr, I create a drop down menu, user selects the file and I get the filepath

(2) I read the filepath in through my `testPandas` function and I would delete the first two rows

---

At first I was thinking the CSV wasn't getting edited because the path wasn't wrapped in quotations so thats why I added in `wrapQuotes` but that didn't look like it did anything.

When I run my program, the csv stays the same.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: first simply use `print()` to see what you get in dataframe before you write it.

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run in console ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: to wrap `filePath` you have to get result from function `filePath = wrapQuotes(filePath)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you use [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) as an inplace method. By default, most pandas methods are not inplace and you'll need to assign the returned object to something inorder to use it or you can use the `inplace = True` argument in the method's caller:

```py
def testPandas(filePath):
    data = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    data = data.drop(data.index[[1,2]])
    data.to_csv(filePath, index = False)
```

or

```py
def testPandas(filePath):
    data = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    data.drop(data.index[[1,2]], inplace=True)
    data.to_csv(filePath, index = False)
```

Should fix your issue. The other function with wrapping quotes is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You make the same mistake two times - you have to assign result to variable

```
data = data.drop(...)
```

and

```
filePath = wrapQuotes(filePath)
```

BTW: you don't need to wrap file path to read it.

---

Eventually you can use option `inplace=True`

```
data.drop(..., inplace=True)
```